# Why does multiprocessing.Pool.__exit__() call terminate() instead of close()?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The documentation for [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) states the following (slightly abbreviated):

> Pool objects support the context management protocol. `__enter__()` returns the pool object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

Why does `__exit__()` call [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) and not [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.close)? Wouldn't it be better if it called `close()`? That would wait until all tasks are completed before shutting down the pool.

To see why I am asking, consider `open()`. Upon `__exit__()`, it calls `close()` on the returned file object, which ensures that all buffered data have been written to disk. It would not make sense for `__exit__()` to call some terminate-like function that would not guarantee that all data were flushed. Or would it?

Comment: fwiw, this is the patch that added this behaviour: http://bugs.python.org/issue15064  there's an additional comment in 2015 voicing an identical concern to this question.  Perhaps open a bug in the python bug tracker?

Comment: use join() and then close()?

Comment: @J.Goedhart: `join()` should be called only after `terminate()` or `close()` [[ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join)]

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Thanks for the link. I am glad that I am not the only one who finds the current behavior inconsistent.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: I have filed a report to the Python bug tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue29954

Comment: Indeed `__exit__` should call `close(); join()` to simplify the obvious use case.